# How to override Angular 2 provider from external module

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

I have a separate `LocalizationModule` that contains `LocaleService` which has `defaultLanguage` as dependency:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocaleService {
    constructor(defaultLanguage: string) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

So now I have to provide factory to create this dependency when injector tries to resolve it:

```
let localeServiceFactory = () => {
    return new LocaleService('en-US');
};

export let localeServiceProvider = {
    provide: LocaleService,
    useFactory: localeServiceFactory
};
```

And I have in my `LocalizationModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        i18nServiceProvider
    ]
})
export class LocalizationModule { }
```

This is bundled as a library and packaged into npm registry. Now I want to use this module in my many apps, but I have to be able to configure default language. How can I override i18nServiceProvider with my own provider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providers added to `AppModule` directly, always override providers from imported modules.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [LocalizationModule],
  providers: [localeServiceProvider],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This doesn't work and still throws the exception about no provider for string.

Comment: Are you lazy loading any of the modules?

Comment: Yes, using angular2-router-loader, but I'm trying to use my LocalizationModule in main AppModule. Also, to clarify my previous comment, If I create my own provider and provide another default language - language is still 'en-US'. If I rebuild my library LocalizationModule so that it provides LocaleService without provider, it will throw no provider for string exception.

Comment: Lazy loaded modules get their own root scope and providers in `AppModule` are only found in non-lazy loaded modules and in lazy loaded modules, that don't have a provider registered for the token (type). Besides that, it's hard to tell from here.

Comment: Actually what is `i18nServiceProvider`?

Comment: that's localeServiceProvider, I just made a typo :) anyway, I was just stupid, **everything works**! I accidentally imported class from a wrong path and has given provider not for the LocaleService, but for some empty, non-existent class which was never really imported. It's strange that my editor didn't give me any errors. I have tackled with this problem for over a couple hours and your answer reassured me that **this** should work, so I looked from the other angle at what might be wrong with my code.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Thanks for the feedback :)